# The MPI program doesn't execute when the number of nodes is greater than 3

Tags: c++, c, mpi, openmpi

Set the number of nodes to 3, the program will run normally when the following commands are executed:

```
[changmx@gpu02 mpiTest]$ mpiexec -n 4 -host gpu02,gpu03,gpu04 helloworld
[gpu04:16537] [[37424,0],2] remote spawn is NULL!
[gpu03:01562] [[37424,0],1] remote spawn is NULL!
Hello World! Process 1 of 4 on gpu02
Hello World! Process 3 of 4 on gpu04
Hello World! Process 0 of 4 on gpu02
Hello World! Process 2 of 4 on gpu03

[changmx@gpu02 mpiTest]$ mpiexec -n 4 -host gpu02,gpu03,gpu05 helloworld
[gpu03:01597] [[37381,0],1] remote spawn is NULL!
[gpu05:26312] [[37381,0],2] remote spawn is NULL!
Hello World! Process 0 of 4 on gpu02
Hello World! Process 1 of 4 on gpu02
Hello World! Process 2 of 4 on gpu03
Hello World! Process 3 of 4 on gpu05
```

But when the number of nodes is 4, the program will neither execute nor exit unless I type Ctrl C to exit:

```
[changmx@gpu02 mpiTest]$ mpiexec -n 4 -host gpu02,gpu03,gpu04,gpu05 helloworld
[gpu04:16671] [[37833,0],2] remote spawn is NULL!
[gpu03:01731] [[37833,0],1] remote spawn is NULL!
```

Below is my source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

#include <mpi.h>

#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <device_launch_parameters.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int myrank, numprocs;
    int namelen = 20;
    char process_name[namelen];

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &myrank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numprocs);

    MPI_Get_processor_name(process_name, &namelen);

    printf("Hello World! Process %d of %d on %s\n", myrank, numprocs, process_name);

    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

My Open MPI version is 1.8.8.

Comment: `1.8.8` is a legacy Open MPI. you should really upgrade to a supported version.

Comment: @Gilles Gouaillardet Thank you for your reply, I don't have root access to the server, so I'm trying to fix this without upgrading the software.

Comment: you do not need root access, simply build and install Open MPI in your user directory

Comment: If this is a student environment, then installing MPI might be out of scope of the assignment. Just report the issue to the system admin and for now use 3 hosts or less.

Comment: The *first* thing your program should do is `MPI_Init`.

Answer (score 0):

This problem should be caused by the incorrect installation of my Open MPI. When I changed the Open MPI version, this problem didn't appear again.